# document.getElementById(idz.toString()) causing Type Error: typ1 is null javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a check box when button is pressed and also delete the same checkbox when the delete is pressed. Unfortunatly the delete function cannot run as it seems that the newly created div doesn't exist yet. How can I get around this?

```
<script>
    const list = document.getElementById("list");
    const cli_form = document.getElementById("client-form");
    let idz = 0;

    function add_client(input) {

        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", idz.toString())


        const newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
        newCheckbox.setAttribute("type", 'checkbox');
        newCheckbox.setAttribute("id", 'checkbox');

        const newLabel = document.createElement("label");
        newLabel.setAttribute("for", 'checkbox');
        newLabel.innerHTML = input.value;

        const br = document.createElement("br");

        const del = document.createElement("input");
        del.setAttribute("type", 'button');
        del.setAttribute("value", idz.toString());
        del.onclick = delete_item(document.getElementById(idz.toString()));

        div.appendChild(newCheckbox);
        div.appendChild(newLabel);
        div.appendChild(del);
        div.appendChild(br);

        list.appendChild(div);
        idz++;
    }

    function delete_item(item1) {
        item1.remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: At that point you haven't actually added the element to the page so it will be `null`.

Comment: A shot into the dark: You add the eventlistner onlick too early.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result of the function `delete_item` which invoke immediately. Therefore, it is removing the item before it is being added to DOM.
You might use an arrow wrapper to avoid immediate invocation.
Like this :

```
del.onclick = () => delete_item(document.getElementById(idz.toString()));
```